# How to keep recording in keyboard module until the program is terminated

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard-events, keylogger

I am using `keyboard` module in Python to record keystrokes.

`data = keyboard.record(until='esc')`
This will keep recording the keystrokes until 'escape' key is pressed. So once I press the escape key, it stops recording and `data` stores the keywords.

But if I close the program forcefully, `data` will not store anything. What can I do so that it keeps recording until the user closes the program, either forcefully or if I shut down my computer, and stores the recorded data in `data`?

Answer (score 0):

First I don't know why you want to do this, but I guess it would stop recording when you either quit the program or even shut down your pc anyway. Maybe if you don't want stop recording until computer shutdown, then just don't press 'escape' right?

Comment: I am sorry I think I have not explained my problem clearly. Please read the edited question